# Querying Hive from Apache Drill causes Stackoverflow error

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, stack-overflow, apache-drill

I am trying to see a table named customers, in hive from drill. I am using Drill in Embedded mode. I am using the default derby database for hive metastore.

When I do a describe, it shows all the columns and types.

But, when I do a select command like this,

```
select * from customers limit 10;
```

In the Web UI, this is what I got

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: StackOverflowError

Hive plugin:

```
 {
  "type": "hive",
  "enabled": true,
  "configProps": {
    "hive.metastore.uris": "thrift://ip_address:9083",
    "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL": "jdbc:derby:;databaseName=../sample-data/drill_hive_db;create=true",
    "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir": "/user/hive/warehouse",
    "fs.default.name": "file///",
    "hive.metastore.sasl.enabled": "false"
  }
}
```

Errors showed in the Log file:

> org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.ForemanException: Unexpected
>   exception during fragment initialization: java.lang.AssertionError:
>   Internal error: Error while applying rule DrillPushProjIntoScan,
>
> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:355)
>   ~[hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar:na]

And, finally this

> Query failed: org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException:
>   SYSTEM ERROR: StackOverflowError

And, the versions i am using are:

Apache Drill : 1.3.0

Hive : 0.13.1-cdh5.3.0

Hadoop : 2.5.0-cdh5.3.0

Comment: I am able to query the same table from hive but drill throws this error.

Comment: Are you trying from Drill shell or Drill Web UI? Drill embedded or cluster mode?

Comment: I tried from both the UI and the shell. Both of them say, Stackoverflow error

Comment: I've edited the question. Added the storage plugin info.

Comment: can you please check `/user/hive/warehouse`  directory in hadoop? I hope you filled all the values from `hive-site.xml`

Comment: yeah, I've filled the values in plugin from hive-site.xml.
And, .../warehouse directory exists in hadoop. It has the Customers table and two other tables which i see when i do "Show tables;"

Comment: Do one more thing please try `select count(*) from customers`

Comment: Its is giving the same thing. StackOverflow Error.

Comment: please go to <drill directory>/log/sqlline.log and get exact stack trace for this error

Comment: I have added a few snippets from Log file in the question.

Comment: can you please share versions for hadoop, hive & drill

Comment: Versions of s/w's updated.

Comment: can you try running hive in Remote Metastore mode rather embedded one (with derby)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a version conflict I guess.

According to Drill's Documentation:

> Drill 1.0 supports Hive 0.13. Drill 1.1 supports Hive 1.0.

So, for 1.1+ you may get issues with hive 0.13.
Read more [here](https://drill.apache.org/docs/hive-storage-plugin/).

So upgrade hive to 1.0 or downgrade drill to 1.0 to test this.

Comment: I have downgraded Drill to v1.0 and this time i got a new error saying,
 `Error while applying rule DrillPushProjIntoScan,` followed by each column name and $(number). Something like, Column1=$0,column2=$1  and so on.

Comment: I will try tomorrow with drill 1.0 and hive 0.13 so that I can reproduce the same issue..